# Referencing library project and getting NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror, library-project

I have seen versions of this question before, but none seemed to have an exact explanation for me. I am currently working on an Android project with [this library](https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers) and am using Android Studio

There is a method in my main project in which I try to instantiate a DatePickerBuilder object, the class is defined in my library project.

```
private OnFocusChangeListener openCalendarDialogFocus = new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {


            int resID = com.doomonafireball.betterpickers.R.style.BetterPickersDialogFragment_Light;

            // Here I get the "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.doomonafireball.betterpickers.datepicker.DatePickerBuilder" error
            // adding com.doomonafireball.betterpickers.datepicker.DatePickerBuilder 
            // to the front of my DatePickerBuilder object does not have any effect

            DatePickerBuilder dpb = new DatePickerBuilder()
                    .setFragmentManager(getSupportFragmentManager())
                    .setStyleResId(resID);
            dpb.show();
        }
    }
};
```

I believe I have this library added properly, it is not a jar file so it is added as another project. I am wondering why this class from the library cannot be found, but the reference to the line above has no problem.
In fact, before the app even runs, the logcat says

```
Could not find class 'com.doomonafireball.betterpickers.datepicker.DatePickerBuilder', referenced from method
```

Which seems strange, because that ^ is the exact path to this class even though it isn't stated in the method.

At the top of my class, I also have the import statement

```
import com.doomonafireball.betterpickers.datepicker.DatePickerBuilder;
```

but it says 'unused import statement'

I feel like I am missing something but am close, any advice would be very much appreciated!

Comment: could you post build.gradle?